# Alert manager is not triggering any alerts

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

There are alerts in Prometheus but slack firing is not happening . Alertmanager says no alerts. i'm attaching the config files of alertmanager and prometheus rules.

Need some immediate help as this is a production related issue.
prometheus-rules.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: prometheus-rules-conf
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  kubernetes_alerts.yml: |
    groups:
      - name: kubernetes_alerts
        rules:
        - alert: DeploymentGenerationOff
          expr: kube_deployment_status_observed_generation != kube_deployment_metadata_generation
          for: 5m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            description: Deployment generation does not match expected generation {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.deployment }}
            summary: Deployment is outdated
        - alert: DeploymentReplicasNotUpdated
          expr: ((kube_deployment_status_replicas_updated != kube_deployment_spec_replicas)
            or (kube_deployment_status_replicas_available != kube_deployment_spec_replicas))
            unless (kube_deployment_spec_paused == 1)
          for: 5m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            description: Replicas are not updated and available for deployment {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.deployment }}
            summary: Deployment replicas are outdated
        - alert: PodzFrequentlyRestarting
          expr: increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[1h]) > 5
          for: 10m
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            description: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} was restarted {{ $value }} times within the last hour
            summary: Pod is restarting frequently
        - alert: KubeNodeNotReady
          expr: kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} == 0
          for: 1h
          labels:
            severity: warning
          annotations:
            description: The Kubelet on {{ $labels.node }} has not checked in with the API,
              or has set itself to NotReady, for more than an hour
            summary: Node status is NotReady
        - alert: KubeManyNodezNotReady
          expr: count(kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} == 0)
            > 1 and (count(kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} ==
            0) / count(kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"})) > 0.2
          for: 1m
          labels:
            severity: critical
          annotations:
            description: '{{ $value }}% of Kubernetes nodes are not ready'
        - alert: APIHighLatency
          expr: apiserver_latency_seconds:quantile{quantile="0.99",subresource!="log",verb!~"^(?:WATCH|WATCHLIST|PROXY|CONNECT)$"} > 4
          for: 10m
          labels:
            severity: critical
          annotations:
            description: the API server has a 99th percentile latency of {{ $value }} seconds for {{ $labels.verb }} {{ $labels.resource }}
        - alert: APIServerErrorsHigh
          expr: rate(apiserver_request_count{code=~"^(?:5..)$"}[5m]) / rate(apiserver_request_count[5m]) * 100 > 5
          for: 10m
          labels:
            severity: critical
          annotations:
            description: API server returns errors for {{ $value }}% of requests
        - alert: KubernetesAPIServerDown
          expr: up{job="kubernetes-apiservers"} == 0
          for: 10m
          labels:
            severity: critical
          annotations:
            summary: Apiserver {{ $labels.instance }} is down!
        - alert: KubernetesAPIServersGone
          expr:  absent(up{job="kubernetes-apiservers"})
          for: 10m
          labels:
            severity: critical
          annotations:
            summary: No Kubernetes apiservers are reporting!
            description: Werner Heisenberg says - OMG Where are my apiserverz?
  prometheus_alerts.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: prometheus_alerts
      rules:
      - alert: PrometheusConfigReloadFailed
        expr: prometheus_config_last_reload_successful == 0
        for: 10m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          description: Reloading Prometheus configuration has failed on {{$labels.instance}}.
      - alert: PrometheusNotConnectedToAlertmanagers
        expr: prometheus_notifications_alertmanagers_discovered < 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          description: Prometheus {{ $labels.instance}} is not connected to any Alertmanagers
  node_alerts.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: node_alerts
      rules:
      - alert: HighNodeCPU
        expr: instance:node_cpu:avg_rate5m > 80
        for: 10s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: High Node CPU of {{ humanize $value}}% for 1 hour
      - alert: DiskWillFillIn4Hours
        expr: predict_linear(node_filesystem_free_bytes{mountpoint="/"}[1h], 4*3600) < 0
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: Disk on {{ $labels.instance }} will fill in approximately 4 hours.
      - alert: KubernetesServiceDown
        expr: up{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints"} == 0
        for: 10m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: Pod {{ $labels.instance }} is down!
      - alert: KubernetesServicesGone
        expr:  absent(up{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints"})
        for: 10m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: No Kubernetes services are reporting!
          description: Werner Heisenberg says - OMG Where are my servicez?
      - alert: CriticalServiceDown
        expr: node_systemd_unit_state{state="active"} != 1
        for: 2m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: Service {{ $labels.name }} failed to start.
          description: Service {{ $labels.instance }} failed to (re)start service {{ $labels.name }}.
  proxy_alert.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: proxy_alert
      rules:
      - alert: Proxy_Down
        expr: probe_success{instance="http://ip",job="blackbox"} == 0
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: Proxy Server {{ $labels.instance }} is down!
      kubernetes_rules.yml: |
    groups:
      - name: kubernetes_rules
        rules:
        - record: apiserver_latency_seconds:quantile
          expr: histogram_quantile(0.99, rate(apiserver_request_latencies_bucket[5m])) / 1e+06
          labels:
            quantile: "0.99"
        - record: apiserver_latency_seconds:quantile
          expr: histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(apiserver_request_latencies_bucket[5m])) / 1e+06
          labels:
            quantile: "0.9"
        - record: apiserver_latency_seconds:quantile
          expr: histogram_quantile(0.5, rate(apiserver_request_latencies_bucket[5m])) / 1e+06
          labels:
            quantile: "0.5"
```

prometheus - configmap yaml

```
alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          regex: alertmanager
          action: keep
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          regex: monitoring
          action: keep
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number]
          action: keep
          regex: 9093
rule_files:
      - "/var/prometheus/rules/*_rules.yml"
      - "/var/prometheus/rules/*_alerts.yml"
```

Even though im getting endpoint in prometheus, alert is still not getting triggerd.

Comment: Are the alerts firing in Prometheus and not sending to slack? Or just the alerts are not firing? I don't see any settings in your prom config to suggest these alerts should be forwarded to slack?

Comment: Hey so the alerts got triggred but this custom config which i have given isnt reflecting in prometheus. I would require help on that                                            ```                                                                                                         proxy_alert.yml: |
    groups: ``` This portion in the above yaml file attached.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem:** you've set an alert on prometheus ,but it doesn't trigger an event. I've gathered few **Rules of thumb** for verifying your alert is set properly, updated and works on prometheus dashboard like a charm:

1. Make sure your **code is updated and deployed** in your ec2 machine (quick glance in your source code)
2. Verify you **yml file written in correct identation**
3. Your **new alert file is targeted on** `prometheus.yml` on `rule_files` key and in the right internal path.
4. Make sure **AlertManager service restarted** in docker & **Prometheus scraper is reloaded** properly (verify in logs).

(To do so use)

```
docker restart <alert-manager-service-name>
curl -X POST localhost:9090/-/reload
```

5. Locate your new alert on `localhost:9090/alerts` and verify that the **condition statement is valid** and should trigger an event (event -> route -> receiver).
6. The receiver should connect third party service with **correct and valid authentication token** (for slack / pager duty / jira etc...)